# Set Polymer paper-badge label with JavaScript

Tags: polymer, paper-badge

How can I set the `label` of a `paper-badge` with JavaScript?

I have tried this but is does not work:

```
Polymer.dom(document.getElementById("id_of_tag")).label = "5";
```

A more complete code snippet is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = new WebSocket(((window.location.protocol === "https:") ? "wss://" : "ws://") + window.location.host + "/ws");
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket); stompClient.debug = null;
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue",
        function(m, h) {
            response = JSON.parse(m.body);
            badge = Polymer.dom(document.getElementById("notificationsLabel"));
            badge.label = "5";
        } ,{ "id" : "${currentUserId}" }
    );
}, function(e) {
    console.log("openWebSocket error", e);
});
</script>

<!-- a lot more stuff -->

<paper-badge id="notificationsLabel" for="notifications" label="0"></paper-badge>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: can you post a snippet?

Comment: I can in about 5 hours from home, I don't have access to the code now. Will do so later.

Comment: Snippet added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to set it inside a Polymer element prefer

```
this.$.id.label
```

or if it's inside a `dom-repeat` or `dom-if`

```
this.$$('#id').label
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-badge/paper-badge.html">
<dom-module id="accessing-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      .myDiv {
        width: 250px;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="insideBadge" class="myDiv">badge inside element</div>
    <paper-badge for="insideBadge" id="insideOwnDom" label="1"></paper-badge>
    <div on-tap="_changeLabel">Click me to change all labels</div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'accessing-element',
    _changeLabel: function() {
      this.$.insideOwnDom.label = 2;

      var docLevel = document.getElementById('inSameDoc');
      docLevel.label = 3;

      var anotherElement = document.querySelector('another-element');
      var ele = Polymer.dom(anotherElement.root);
      var badge = ele.getEffectiveChildNodes()[3];
      badge.label = 4;
      // or
      //            anotherElement.label= 4;
    }
  })
</script>


<dom-module id="another-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      .myDiv {
        width: 250px;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="anotherELementsBadge" class="myDiv">badge inside another element</div>
    <paper-badge id="anotherElementsDom" for="anotherELementsBadge" label="{{label}}"></paper-badge>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'another-element',
    properties: {
      label: {
        type: Number,
        value: 1
      }
    }
  })
</script>


<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Change labels</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .myDiv {
      width: 250px;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
  </style>
  <div style="height:100px;"></div>
  <div id="docBadge" class="myDiv">badge at same doc level</div>
  <paper-badge for="docBadge" id="inSameDoc" label="1"></paper-badge>
  <another-element></another-element>
  <accessing-element></accessing-element>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In fact I try to set the label from outside. In a custom element of mine I calculate a number, and I want to set it as label of the paper-badge which is outside my custom element, somewhere in the navigation.

Comment: As your badge is in another element first you'll have to select that element and then select label from it's shadow dom or better still you can bind label of badge to a property of your element in which badge is, then select that element(which i assume is at document level) using `getElementById` and then update the property which is binded to label of paper-badge

Comment: The badge is on the same page, but not inside a different element. If I add console.log(badge); I see it in the logs. I also see its "label"-property changing, it just looks like it does not redraw.

Comment: i've added snippet covering three different cases. Hope it helps